# Three List-sources in the same ScrollView

Tags: xaml, listview, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

So I have a ViewModel with three `List<object>` with different types of objects. I want to have three collapsable sections in a ListView(or other usable control) with one List as source for each of them.

My thought is:

```
<ScrollView>
     <StackPanel>
          <ListView></ListView>
          <ListView></ListView>
          <ListView></ListView>
     <StackPanel>
</ScrollView>
```

But I struggle with disable scrolling in ListView and enable scrolling on the StackPanel.

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care much about virtualization (not expecting very many items), just replaces `ListView`s with `ItemsControl`s.

If your items have the same base class, you may consider using a grouped `ListView` with 3 groups, one for each "list".

Comment: What will i lose if I choose ItemsControl? Most of the listitems are a couple of textblocks and itemcount will not be more than 30.

Comment: you will loose virtualization